# Compare git commits on different branches

Tags: git, gitk

I have two branches - master and experimental. How can I see which commits are in experimental and not in master? It would be nice to see this in gitk, but in the terminal is also ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see that using 'git log' :

```
git log master..experimental
```

That will show you which commits are in experimental but not in master.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for selecting revisions is documented in `man gitrevisions`. In commands that deal with an entire set of revisions, just naming one means "everything reachable from" that one, and appending a caret `^` to the front means "but not anything reachable from this one", and `A..B` is an alternate spelling of `^A B`.

(edit: oh, boy, I had the A..B exactly backwards.)

Comment: thanks. It is a useful information. Unfortunatly I cannot mark two answers.